# Firestore orderBy fetches 0 documents

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an orderBy query like this:

```
  async list() {
    const snapshot = await this.firestore
      .collection("queue")
      .orderBy(`ignoreUserIds.Po0fouROHVQnrV1ZR17L8Tql3OJ2`)
      .limit(10)
      .get();
    return snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data());
  }
```

But when I run it, it returns 0 documents while there are documents in the collection.

The document has a different userId in the map. But that shouldn't matter, right? orderBy should return all the documents and just order them?

I also made an index:

[image]

This is what a document looks like

[image]

I want to find all the documents but just ordered on the field.

Comment: I believe you need to add `.get()` to your query.

Comment: I have, this is just the query. I will add it into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I run it, it returns 0 documents

That's the expected behavior since, inside the "ignoreUserIds" Map, there is no key that is equal to "Po0fouROHVQnrV1ZR17L8Tql3OJ2".

> The document has a different userId in the map.

That's the reason why you are getting no documents.

> But that shouldn't matter right?

No, it indeed matters.

> orderBy should return all the documents and just order them?

No, it won't since you are trying to order on a field that actually doesn't exist.

> I want to find all the documents but just ordered on the field

To achieve that, you have to use the exact UID (aKWp...VNo2) that exists in the database.

You might also take into consideration using either [not equal (!=)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_) or [not-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) it better fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

An `orderBy()` clause has a limitation that it also filters for **existence** of the given field. The result set will not include documents that do not contain the given field.

For example, let's say a Firestore collection `users` contains 3 documents `user1`, `user2` and `user3`. Every document has a field `ignoreUserIds` of type Map which contains `id : 4`, `id2 : 2` and `id3 : 5` for `user1`, `user2` and `user3` respectively.

```
users------>
    user1------>
        ignoreUserIds : 
                id : 4
    user2----->
        ignoreUserIds : 
                id2 : 2
    user3----->
        ignoreUserIds : 
                id3 : 5
```

The following queries will give the corresponding results

```
db.collection("users").orderBy('ignoreUserIds.id').get() => only user1
db.collection("users").orderBy('ignoreUserIds.id2').get() => only user2 
db.collection("users").orderBy('ignoreUserIds.id3').get() => only user3 
db.collection("users").orderBy('ignoreUserIds.id4').get() => 0 documents //as there are no documents inside the collection 'users' containing the field 'ignoreUserIds.id4'.
```

In your case, it seems, the field mentioned in the `orderBy()` clause, `ignoreUserIds.Po0fouROHVQnrV1ZR17L8Tql3OJ2`, is not present in any of the documents inside the `queue` collection. This is the reason you are getting 0 documents.

Additionally, as you want to sort the documents based on the userIds present inside the `ignoreUserIds` field, I would suggest you to mention only `ignoreUserIds` inside the orderBy clause which will sort the documents based on the userIds present inside the `ignoreUserIds` field.

So your query should look like the following -

```
const snapshot = await this.firestore
      .collection("queue")
      .orderBy(‘ignoreUserIds’)
      .limit(10)
      .get();
```

You can refer to [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) to know more about the `orderBy()` clause and its limitations.